# jQuery - Serialize Form Post Values

Tags: php, jquery, html

How do I want to post a form using `jquery serialize` function? I tried to post the form value but on the php part, the value is not shown. Below are my codes:

**html**

```
<form name="myform"> 
    ID  : <input type="text" name="id_staff" id="id_staff">
    <select name="sort" id="sort">
        <option value="0">Choose Status</option>
        <option value="1">All</option>
        <option value="2">Pending</option>
        <option value="3">Approve</option>
        <option value="4">Not Approve</option>
    </select> &nbsp;<input type="button" id="submit" value="Papar" />
    <div id="loader"></div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var sort = $("#sort").val(),
    id_staff = $("#id_staff").val(),
    data = $('form').serialize();

    $.post('result.php',
    {
        data : data
    }, function(data){
        $("#loader").fadeOut(400);
        $("#result").html(data);
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["sort"])){   
    $sort = $_REQUEST['sort'];
    $id_staff = $_REQUEST['id_staff'];

    echo "Your Id : $id_staff <p/>";
    echo "You choose : $sort";
}
```

If I console.log(data), I get: `id_staff=12345&sort=1`

Answer (score 2):

Your server is receiving a string that looks something like this (which it should if you're using jQuery serialize()):

```
"param1=someVal&param2=someOtherVal"
```

...something like this is probably all you need:

```
$params = array();
parse_str($_GET, $params);
```

`$params` should then be an array that contains all the form element as `indexes`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It works but I am able to do it in different way. Will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `.serialize`, you can get rid of this:

```
 var sort = $("#sort").val(),
 id_staff = $("#id_staff").val(),
```

You data will be available as follows with `.serialize`:

```
your-url.com/sort=yoursortvalue&id_staff=youridstaff
```

It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {


     $("#myform").submit(function() {
      var datastring = $( this ).serialize();

          $.post('result.php',
        {
            data : datastring
        }, function(data){
            $("#loader").fadeOut(400);
            $("#result").html(data);
        });
        })
 })
```

On PHP side you simple need to access it using the `$_GET['sort']`.

**Edit:**

To view the data, you should define a div with id `result` so that the result returned is displayed within this div.

**Example:**

```
<div id="result"></div>
<form name="myform"> 
    ID  : <input type="text" name="id_staff" id="id_staff">
    <select name="sort" id="sort">
        <option value="0">Choose Status</option>
        <option value="1">All</option>
        <option value="2">Pending</option>
        <option value="3">Approve</option>
        <option value="4">Not Approve</option>
    </select> &nbsp;<input type="button" id="submit" value="Papar" />
    <div id="loader"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: For `.serialize` I have to use the form `.submit` is it?

Comment: No, but it make more sense to use `.submit` when you submit a form. I have optimised the code above by using `$(this).serialize()`. Let me know if your problem is solved. :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still show no data. I tried to `echo $_GET['sort']` but no value is shown.

Comment: Where are you looking for the data? Since this is an ajax request, you should look for it in your chrome console > `Network` > `result.php` > `Response tab` and not on your html page.

Comment: How do I want to view it on my html page? On the console panel, the data is pass on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138786/discussion-between-amran-and-hyder-b).

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do it this way:

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var form = $("#myform");

        $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'result.php',
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#result").html(response);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error Submitting');
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST["id_staff"])){   
    $sort = $_POST['sort'];
    $id_staff = $_POST['id_staff'];

    echo "<p>Your Id : $id_staff</p>";
    echo "You choose : $sort";
}
```

Do give a comment if it need improvement or better solution.

Comment: You don't really need to do this `var form = $("#myform");` and then use `form.serialize`. There's nothing wrong with it but a better way would be using `$('this').serialize()` directly.